# Hay un máximo de puntos en Line Chart?

Tags: android, gráficas

Estoy representando una serie de puntos en una gráfica hecha en Android con la herramienta LineChart.

Tengo una serie de puntos obtenidos a través de un json. Los puntos se componen de fecha y valor.

Estos puntos, pertenecen al intervalo [ayer, hoy]. Siempre recuperamos los puntos del día anterior y los del día actual.

A la hora de generar la gráfica no obtengo ningún error ni me entra en ningún catch por lo cual deduzco que no salta ninguna excepción.

Mi problema es que, al tener un dato cada minuto, se genera una cantidad "grande" de datos a representar y no me "pinta" todos en la gráfica.

Así es como se ve la gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Como se puede ver, quedan más de la mitad de valores sin representar y a la hora de generar la gráfica si que le paso puntos que deberían estar en esa zona vacía.

¿Puede ser que Line Chart tenga un límite máximo de puntos que pueda representar? No he visto nada en su página.

La página con documentación de la herramienta LineChart es la siguiente: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Puedo poner el código que utilizo para rellenar la gráfica si es necesario.